# Icy roads during early spring

Tags: temperature

In the middle of the day of early spring, the snow is wet everywhere due to high temperature, while in the afternoon the snow becomes icy and hard on the road and in the forest it is still soft. 
Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because soil retains heat better than roads (i.e. thermal conductivity lower).

Comment: I know it is about something related to the reflection of the sunlight on the snow but I can't figure out more than that.

Comment: @Anonym that doesn't seem as probable explanation. Snow is snow, it reflects everywhere the same and in forest there is even less sunlight to heat it up. I think Allura is on to something. At the afternoon, the snow is probably still heated by the heat stored in soil, while at the same time forest makes it impossible for wind to take the heat away. Is the snow hard only on the road, or also everywhere on the open? Is the road inside the forest or on the open?

Comment: By road I mean on the streets while you are walking

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, **radiation** is the biggest player in this study case.
In the afternoon, the sun goes down.
Road's snow exchanging with empty sky (apparent temperature of -50°C) let it icing.
Forest's snow exchanges with sky, that has a little portion of empty sky, the rest of the sky is occupied by trees which have an higher temperature. This does not make the snow freezing.

---

This is an **heat exchange** issue.
Heat exchange happens in three way:

1. Conduction
2. Convection
3. Radiation

In first instance we can neglect point *2* because major effect comes from conduction and radiation.

Let's analyse the players:

- *Snow* lies on *ground* that we can consider at constant temperature during the day, or better, it has lower, slower and delayed temperature oscillation;
- *Snow* faces to the surrounding environment, that's **sky** (on the road, **A**) and **trees** (in the forest, **B**); and of the same important, the **sun**.

Now, analyse the two situation:

- In the morning, snow is frozen. *(let's take it as a starting point; the reason why directly comes from the same reasons I will explain later)*
- During the day, it starts melting down thanks to the sun.
- In the afternoon the sun goes down.

Prior to go further let me point the two cases:

- both in **A** and **B** case, snow exchanges heat with *sky* on top, and with *ground* on bottom
- the main difference, is that **A** sky's in "empty", while **B** sky's "contains" many trees
- remember that **sky** (and with it I mean the portion of sky that "cover up" the space) has a mean temperature (relevant to radiation heat exchange) of -50°C *[academic reminiscence, needs a proper citation]*

Now, go to the heart of the problem, that's what happens to snow?

- case **A**, exchanging heat with empty sky, it will start lowering down its temperature and in a little to big amount of time snow freezes
- case **B**, exchanging heat with non-empty sky, it will start lowering down its temperature and in a little to big amount of time snow freezes (yes, the same as above!).

So, what makes difference is the **speed** in which it will happen: while for case **A** we can assume a -50°C (thus fast freezing), for the latter case we have a much lower apparent temperature and this is due to **1)** free-sky portion is much lower **2)** surrounding trees are covered by snow which we can assume at 0°C.

***NB: if we let this two cases running, they will both get freeze.***

As last step we have to (not) take into account **conduction** exchange between snow and ground. Let me shrink the issue to: ground's temperature **follows delayed** the snow temperature: in the afternoon, ground's temperature will be more of less 0°C. This means ground have a "buoy" effect on the freeze snow, "helping" it to stay melt.

---

You can calculate how much my approximation is true/good with the help of some dimensionless numbers, the ones like Nusselt number.
I think in this explanation would be useless complicating the case with **convection** but just for the sake of completeness, it **would have had** a "negative" effect on snow: if you catch a temperature-hour during the day graph you will notice **air temperature** reach the top around at 16 o' clock, this means convection **has** a melting effect on snow; this effect is not the same open-air (above the road) and in the forest due to the present of obstacles (trees) that lower down the wind, thus the *ability* of it to *take in* heat.

Comment: **WIP:** I know, this is a bit mess up but issue is wide, so many points to cover! I will add some images if my question would be right enough, as well as, rework the shape of the answer. Feel free to improve/comments

Comment: thank you soo much i really appreciate it